# small problem comparison script produced in php and jquery

Tags: jquery

I apologize for my bad English. I need a lot of help. I am making a small script to compare products in php and jquery. In the script there are two forms that through the autocomplete function find the products in the mysql database. By clicking on the link, the text is inserted into the input and then the search is carried out. The problem that I cannot solve is that by selecting the first product the text is correctly inserted within the first input, by selecting the second product this is not inserted in the second input but always in the first.

```
<div class="conteiner-form">
<div class="inner-form">
<form class="form-register" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="for-control" name="prd1" id="search" placeholder="Prodotto 1" autocomplete="on" required/>
            <div id="show-list"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="for-control2" name="prd2" id="search2" placeholder="Prodotto 2" autocomplete="on" required/>
            <div id="show-list2"></div>
        </div>
    </form>       
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script_search.js"></script>
<script src="js/script_search2.js"></script>
```

the two js files are as follows

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Send Search Text to the server
    $("#search").keyup(function () {
      let searchText = $(this).val();
      if (searchText != "") {
        $.ajax({
          url: "action-search.php",
          method: "post",
          data: {
            query: searchText,
          },
          success: function (response) {
            $("#show-list").html(response);
          },
        });
      } else {
        $("#show-list").html("");
      }
    });

    // Set searched text in input field on click of search button
    $(document).on("click", "a", function () {
      $("#search").val($(this).text());
    })
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Send Search Text to the server
    $("#search2").keyup(function () {
      let searchText = $(this).val();
      if (searchText != "") {
        $.ajax({
          url: "action-search2.php",
          method: "post",
          data: {
            query: searchText,
          },
          success: function (response) {
            $("#show-list2").html(response);
          },
        });
      } else {
        $("#show-list2").html("");
      }
    });

    // Set searched text in input field on click of search button
    $(document).on("click", "a", function () {
        $("#search2").val($(this).text());
    })
});
```

Comment: In the click handlers, instead of `document`, use the parent `show-list` id reference: `$(document)` to `$('#show-list')`, then do the same for `show-list2`.

Comment: thank you so much! problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the two click handlers, use the parent `show-list` or `show-list2` id reference instead of `document`:

```
$('#show-list').on("click", "a", function () {
  $("#search").val($(this).text());
})

$('#show-list2').on("click", "a", function () {
    $("#search2").val($(this).text());
})
```